# Orbeon JavaScript Embedding: a.querySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript, orbeon

I ma trying to use the orbeon Javascript embedding API, but for some reason I am not able to get it working. I might be missing something. I a, embedding a form into the page and here is a snippet of how i am trying to do it.

```
ORBEON.fr.API.embedForm(
        'div#orbeon-container',
        '/orbeon',
        'App1',
        'Form1',
        'new'
    );
```

I am however getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: a.querySelector is not a function`.
I think this could be because of how i am specifying the container, but i am not sure how it should be specified as the [documentation on embedding](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/javascript-api#embedform-api) doesn't seem to give an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

The docs you linked state the first parameter is of type `HTMLElement` (which isn't quite the same as the CSS Selector you might use to address it).

| Parameter | Optional | Type | Example | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| container | No | HTML element |  | DOM element you want the form to be placed in |

In other words, instead of

```
ORBEON.fr.API.embedForm(
    'div#orbeon-container',
    '/orbeon',
    'App1',
    'Form1',
    'new'
);
```

it should be

```
let orbeonContainer = document.querySelector('#orbeon-container');

ORBEON.fr.API.embedForm(
    orbeonContainer,
    '/orbeon',
    'App1',
    'Form1',
    'new'
);
```

Comment: This did not work when I tried it out (it was the first thing i tried), Let me try that again, may be this time it will work. Thanks

Comment: If this doesn't work then at least the error message must have changed, because `orbeonContainer` will positively have a `querySelector` method, as long as the element actually exists. Now, does it?

Comment: Sorry I have been caught up with other part of the app and I had not gotten time to try this out. I have tried this but still the same issue. It does not fix the problem. cc: @ebruchez

Comment: Oh, wait, i think this might actually work, I am seeing a different issue now, relates to the context. I am trying to load from a different server/API, using `/orbeon` resolves to the same URL as the web app, but I want to load from a different endpoint.

Comment: @ReioSantos Did the JavaScript embedding end up working for you? Feel free to comment here if you still have any outstanding issue with the JavaScript embedding API. -Alex

Comment: It works if orbeon is served from the same context(server) as the front and, but not if it runs on a different host(server with a different URL from the webapp) @ffflabs

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue is that the first parameter must be a DOM element, not a string. Try instead passing the element.